# How to list dates in yyyy_mm format with PHP using a loop?

Tags: php, date, loops, time, for-loop

What's the cleanest way to use a loop in PHP to list dates in the following way?

```
2011_10
2011_09
2011_08
2011_07
2011_06
...
2010_03
2009_02
2009_01
2009_12
2009_11
```

The key elements here:

- Should be as simple as possible - I would prefer one for loop instead of two.
- Should list this month's date as the first date, and should stop at a fixed point (2009-11)
- Should not break in the future (eg: subtracting 30 days worth of seconds will probably work but will eventually break as there are not an exact amount of seconds on each month)

Had to make a few tweaks to the solution:

```
    // Set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // Start date
    $date = date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-01';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2009-1-1';

    while (strtotime($date) >= strtotime($end_date))
    {
        $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($date)));
        echo substr($date,0,7);
        echo "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Title and body don't match. Which format do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this little code does the thing? :
more complicated situations.

```
    <?php
        // Set timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        // Start date
        $date = '2009-12-06';
        // End date
        $end_date = '2020-12-31';

        while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
            echo "$date\n";
            $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        }

 ?>
```

The credit goes to: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-loop-through-dates-from-date-to-date-with-strtotime-function/

Answer (score 0):

This is what im guessing your asking for cause it doesnt really make sense......

```
$startmonth = date("m");
$endmonth = 7;
$startyear = date("Y");
$endyear = 2012;

//First for loop to loop threw years
for($i=$startyear; $i<=$endyear; $i++, $startmonth=0) {
    //Second for loop to loop threw months
    for($o=$startmonth; $o<=12; $o++) {
        //If statement to check and throw stop when at limits
        if($i == $endyear && $o <= $endmonth)
            echo $i."_".$o."<br/>";
        else
            break;
    }
}

Will output:
2012_0
2012_1
2012_2
2012_3
2012_4
2012_5
2012_6
2012_7
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 introduces some great improvements to date/time processing in PHP. For example, the `first day of`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod` being used below.

```
$start    = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('2009-11-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y_m') . PHP_EOL;
}
```